# Split bash string by newline characters

Tags: string, bash, shell

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257398/1197775).

And I am trying this:

```
x='some
   thing'

y=(${x//\n/})
```

And I had no luck, I thought it could work with double backslash:

```
y=(${x//\\n/})
```

But it did not.

To test I am not getting what I want I am doing:

```
echo ${y[1]}
```

Getting:

```
some
thing
```

Which I want to be:

```
some
```

I want `y` to be an array `[some, thing]`. How can I do this?

Comment: Note that `some` would be in `${y[0]}`, not `${y[1]}`, once you solve the newline issue.

Comment: @juanpastas FYI the linked to solution has been updated to include **how to split on a newline character when your input has spaces**. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5257398/52074

Answer (score 181):

Another way:

```
x=$'Some\nstring'
readarray -t y <<<"$x"
```

Or, if you don't have bash 4, the bash 3.2 equivalent:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a y <<<"$x"
```

You can also do it the way you were initially trying to use:

```
y=(${x//$'\n'/ })
```

This, however, will not function correctly if your string already contains spaces, such as `'line 1\nline 2'`. To make it work, you need to restrict the word separator before parsing it:

```
IFS=$'\n' y=(${x//$'\n'/ })
```

...and then, since you are changing the separator, you don't need to convert the `\n` to `space` anymore, so you can simplify it to:

```
IFS=$'\n' y=($x)
```

This approach will function *unless* `$x` contains a matching globbing pattern (such as "`*`") - in which case it will be replaced by the matched file name(s). The `read`/`readarray` methods require newer bash versions, but work in all cases.

Comment: Matching instances of `\n` with `\\n` in the expansion pattern doesn't work; instead, you have to splice in a `\n` *literal*: `echo ${x//$'\n'/ }`.

Comment: The `readarray` approach is actually the *most robust* one, because `($x)` is *still subject to globbing*: if any line happens to be a valid, *single-token* globbing pattern (e.g., `*`), it WILL be expanded, if files happen to match. `readarray` requires bash *4*, however; here's the bash 3.2 equivalent (for those on OS X): `IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a y <<<"$x"`. Since your post is gaining traction, would you mind adding these findings?

Comment: In OS-X/Macland, you have to use bash 3.2 (or at least without updating BASH). Thus the mysterious read -rd ' ' must be used (and works!) the online manual page I found is pretty cryptic about this (http://ss64.com/bash/read.html)...it's pretty mind-bending...does it mean "turn off \n, and then use emptiness as the delimiter?"

Comment: Please remove the horrible `IFS=$'\n' y=($x)` parts from your answer! it's broken when `$x` contains globs (like `*`, `[...]`, etc.) — I know it can be “fixed” with `set -f`, but at this point we're fighting against the shell. The semantically correct ways (and bugfree ways) are the `readarray`/`mapfile` way and the `read` way.

Comment: Also, note that the return code of your `read` command is `1` (e.g., a failure), since the delimiter is not seen at the end of the stream read. The proper way is: `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra y < <(printf '%s;\0' "$x")`, as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash/24426608#24426608). Note that in the case of a space-like character (i.e., space, newline or tab character), consecutive delimiters will be considered as a unique one. So the `read` method is subtly different from the `readarray`/`mapfile` method for newlines.

Comment: To fix the space-like character artifact described in my comment above, you have to use a `while`/`read` loop.

Comment: @Jayen: it does work, but the `readarray` is executed in a subshell, and hence the value of `y` is lost as soon as the subshell exits. See [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: I had to remove quotes from around `$x` in order for the first solution to work.

Comment: Indeed, with `-d ''` you need to [add `\0`](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/f3104ed68fecc07a5b7c153e821fd41f).

Answer (score 9):

There is another way if all you want is the text up to the first line feed:

```sh
x='some
thing'

y=${x%$'\n'*}
```

After that `y` will contain `some` and nothing else (no line feed).

> What is happening here?

We perform a [parameter expansion substring removal](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) (`${PARAMETER%PATTERN}`) for the shortest match up to the first [ANSI C line feed](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) (`$'\n'`) and drop everything that follows (`*`).

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
newStr=`sed ":a;N;s/\n/@@@/g" <<< "$variable"`
```

will replace \n by @@@, and to split correctly, then this use before loop:

```
IFS='@@@'

for a in $newStr
   do ...
```