# Why is read -rd '' required when splitting strings terminated by newlines in bash (3.2)?

Tags: bash, split, newline

The answer to this question on splitting strings by newline characters,
[Split bash string by newline characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771965/split-bash-string-by-newline-characters), seems to say that newlines are the default delimiter, so we should change the delimiter to null, and split on that instead.  Why doesn't splitting on the newline work?  What I would expect (and desire, in my use case) is that there be a 1:1 correlation between lines and \n in the input string (so a \n must be added to get the last line), and that blank lines, leading/imbedded whitespace, etc. would be preserved.

Quoting from Mark Gerolimatos, who seems to be asking the same question:

In OS-X/Macland, you have to use bash 3.2 (or at least without updating BASH). Thus the mysterious read -rd ' ' must be used (and works!) the online manual page I found is pretty cryptic about this (ss64.com/bash/read.html)...it's pretty mind-bending...does it mean "turn off \n, and then use emptiness as the delimiter?"

Comment: The default delimiter is in the value of `IFS` and it is not just `\n`, see the output of `printf '%q\n' "$IFS"`, it is a space, tab and newline, and the `builtin` `read` strips trailing and leading white spaces/tabs by default, hence the use if  `IFS=` to disable that feature What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Show some code that isn't working. We can't help otherwise. Good luck.

Comment: The code works; the question was 'why'?

Comment: My confusion was on the two uses of 'delimiter', and on all the 'helpful' things bash does that are not obvious - splitting without explicitly asking, the implicit newline on <<<, discarded repeat separators, etc.  I upvoted both answers, because the two together gave me the context that I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The confusion happens because `read` operates with *two* delimiters:

1. How much to read
2. How to split what you read

By default, this is:

1. Read until a linefeed (i.e. one line)
2. Split on whitespace (i.e. into words)

If you just set `IFS=$'\n'` you can see the problem:

1. Read until a linefeed (again, one line)
2. Split on linefeed (which doesn't do anything, because one line necessarily can't consist of multiple lines)

What you instead want to do is

1. read *all* input
2. split on linfeed

`read -d ''` causes `read` to read until an ASCII NUL, which is not found in normal text, and is therefore a workable proxy for "read all text input".

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure we're on the same page, this is the code in that answer:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a y <<<"$x"
```

where `x` is the variable to read from and `y` is the array variable to populate with the lines of `x`.

> Why doesn't splitting on the newline work?

It does; the `IFS=$'\n'` is telling `read` to split on newlines.

If you're asking why you can't write `read -rd $'\n' -a y`, then: the delimiter indicated by `-d` tells `read` where to *stop* reading. So if you set that to a newline, then `read` will only read one line!

> What I would […] desire […] is that […] blank lines […] would be preserved.

Yes, it's annoying that initial or consecutive occurrences of the separator get discarded, such that `x=$'\na\n\nb'` gives the same result as `x=$'a\nb'`.

To satisfy your requirements, you'll need to use a slightly different approach, where you call `read` once per line:

```
y=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\n' ; do
  y+=("$REPLY")
done <<< "${x%$'\n'*}"
```

In this approach, we tell `read` to just take the line as-is and not split it (hence `IFS=`), and we handle the looping ourselves.

Note that the `"${x%$'\n'*}"` bit strips off the last newline and everything after it, per your requirement to ignore the last line if it doesn't have a newline. (The `<<<` bit implicitly adds a newline.)